# Expand height of relative <div> to fit height of children absolute <div>

Tags: html, css, height

i have a div with position relative, this div has few children elements with position absolute.
Each children have few elements and display flex column. Their size can be different because the content will not be the same for each children.
How do I expand the height of the parent div to fit exactly the height of all children ?

If you look in inspect element you see the parent div take the width to fit content, but not the height.

( so basically i want the div with the class team to not have height of 0, but i can't give it a fixed height)

```css
.teamate {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.teamate .sub-line {
  width: 25%;
}

.teamate img {
  width: 55%;
}

.teamate p {
  width: 50%;
}

.team {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="team">

    <div class='teamate'>
        <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
        <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
        <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
        <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
        <p>
            Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class='teamate'>
        <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
        <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
        <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
        <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
        <p>
            Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class='teamate'>
        <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
        <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
        <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
        <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
        <p>
            Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class='teamate'>
        <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
        <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
        <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
        <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
        <p>
            Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
        </p>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You can't. Absolute children are not considered for the dimensions of the relative parent. I suggest you rethink your layout method.

Comment: Its not clear what effect you are trying to achieve. Do you have an image of the proposed result?

Comment: Here's an image off the result i want to do : https://ibb.co/Lg0xZtk

Comment: As you see i need the two items on the right to be a bit more down of the page than the two items on the left, i thought relative and absolute might be a good option but apparently with all the downvote i think i was mistaken lmao

Comment: dont use relative and absolute positioning for that as it will be unresponsive and a mess to work with. Easiest way to do it is the use of a 2 column layout either with flexbox or grid. use `nth-child` pseudo-selector to shift the right column below. My anwser for a css-grid solution shows how you can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a 2 column CSS-Grid. That is achieved by using `.team { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }`

Next you add a margin-top to the 2nd child so that the 2nd div (right side) will be moved slightly below.

Because of the grid the 3rd element (2nd element of the left side) will be shifted below aswell. to counter that and for every other following card you add a negative margin equal of the 2nd child margin. to do that, you can use: `.team div:nth-child(2n + 3)` as a selector.

```css
.teamate {
  width: 40%;
}

.teamate .sub-line {
  width: 25%;
}

.teamate img {
  width: 55%;
}

.teamate p {
  width: 50%;
}

.team {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.team div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.team div:nth-child(2n + 3) {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="team">

  <div class='teamate'>
    <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
    <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
    <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
    <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
    <p>
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class='teamate'>
    <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
    <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
    <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
    <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
    <p>
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class='teamate'>
    <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
    <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
    <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
    <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
    <p>
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class='teamate'>
    <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
    <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
    <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
    <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
    <p>
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class='teamate'>
    <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
    <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
    <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
    <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
    <p>
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class='teamate'>
    <img src="style/img/leftphoto.png" alt="">
    <h1>FIRST TEAMATE</h1>
    <h2>ROLE AND POSITION</h2>
    <img class="sub-line" src="style/img/subline.png">
    <p>
      Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate. Long description about teamate.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you tell me what the 'n' stands for in : .team div:nth-child(2n + 3) ?

Comment: @Mathi `n` is a variable with different use that either stands for `0` or `x-element`. in this combination `2n` means every 2nd element. `3n` would be every 3rd element. `+ 3` starting at the 3rd element. so the `2n + 3` as whole is a calculation variable for `3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 ...` - https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/